# Opinion needed regarding Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am fairly new to Laravel. So far I am loving the framework and I am trying to learn the best practices as much as possible. I have a question here I need your expert opinion. I am creating a Reporting Interface. I have separate controller for each type of Report. Each Controller have functions with similar names like (generate, ajax and view). These functions are different in each report by functionality. But I have some similar functions like save_report(that should save report as json on S3) or get_report. I may have more functions like these. I am not sure what is the best way to save these functions. Should I create a Main Report controller that should contain all these functions and then use them or should I create a Model or Trait or is there a better way to do it ?

Please let me know if something is wrong in my initial approach

Thanks

Comment: Can you capture the main point of your question in the title of your post, so that it is useful to future users of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the concept of interfaces and override the methods defined in the interfaces in child classes

Answer (score 0):

As my experience, I have followed as SOLID Principle. I recommended you to go this website to check it and understanding about it. Here is the link: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

In my opinion, Don't include any functions that its not related.